# Determining Polarity Of Unmarked AC Adapter With Voltmeter

Tags: adapter, polarity, voltmeter

I need to replace an adapter that no longer works (for a fibre optic Christmas tree). I do not see any indications for polarity on the adapter (or anywhere else) and I do not have the manual. I read that the polarity of an adapter can be tested with a voltmeter. If the AC adapter is no longer working, would this test still work?

Comment: Probably not. If the AC adapter is no longer working, a voltmeter will not measure what it should normally measure. We can't be sure what you will see, though. Just that it won't likely be accurate. I'd tear into the AC adapter (breaking it open) and just look at what is inside to figure it out, if there are no markings elsewhere.

Comment: You might be able to also take apart the christmas tree and see if there is a ground and that might tell you the polarity

Comment: @jonk Technically all I can say with certainty is that the AC adapter isn't powering the fibre optic tree (while another one, not meant for it does). I'm using the term "no longer working" loosely but I expect an adapter either works or doesn't.

Comment: I don't expect this information will assist in identifying the polarity, but I will include it just in case. // Model: U120200A43 // Input: 120VAC 60Hz 36W // Output: 12VAC 2000mA //

Comment: @KenBoone An adapter may not be able to produce the same current compliance as earlier. If this diminishes enough, the lights won't work but the voltmeter may still measure something useful (or not.) So it's not always an either-or situation and therefore I can't say to you if the meter's reading will help or not in determining polarity, assuming this is a DC output adapter.

Comment: @jonk I believe it's an AC power adapter based on the specs.

Comment: @KenBoone If you have the specs, then you are pretty much done. It's likely that all there is in there is just a transformer. You need to get a new one that yields 12 VAC RMS at the secondary and can comply with as much as 2 A RMS. That is about 25 W. A good one will weigh in at about 2 lbs. A cheap one at about 1 lb. (See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/268840/38098).)

Comment: @jonk To be frank, I'm not savvy with electronics aside from the basics. I went out and bought [this](https://www.amazon.ca/BENSN-Universal-Adapter-Household-Electronics/dp/B083W5HC37/). I set the voltage to 12. The lights on the fibre optic tree lit up briefly and then nothing, I must have damaged the circuitry. I thought maybe it was because I needed to use the included polarity inverter. I was just looking for an explanation for what happened but I expect it's difficult to diagnose remotely.

Comment: @KenBoone That's a DC output, not AC. That very often won't do the job. You need to go to Mouser or Digikey or your favorite electronics parts supplier and find a transformer that accepts your mains AC voltage and provides a secondary with at least 24VA rating (that's 12V times 2A = 24VA.) More would be better, though. I'm not sure if you can accept a 12.6 VAC secondary. Maybe so. But 12 VAC secondaries also exist, if costing slightly more and being slightly less available. I might risk the 12.6 VAC if there was a good reason (cost, availability, delivery time, etc.)

Comment: @jonk Ah yes, I see. When I search the model number, it shows AC/AC adapters NOT AC/DC adapters. Lesson learned. When I was looking for a replacement adapter last week, I did see [this](https://www.amazon.ca/12V-2-0A-Cable-Source-U120200A43/dp/B01MSW00LM) The specs and description matched, the only difference was that it said 24W instead of 36W so I wasn't sure if that was an issue. Should have asked here FIRST lol. Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: @KenBoone That's got the right specs on it. Still, it does NOT look "heavy enough" to me. But I could easily be wrong about that. But if I'm right, it may mean poor regulation and over-heating. Still, my wife would just tell me that my solution is too heavy, cumbersome and then she wouldn't use it. She's probably right. I do like good stuff and am willing to pay the weight penalty for it. (My transistor checker weighs 50 lbs.) You can probably get by with that. And I should stop complaining. ;) You can always just replace it when it catches fire, melts, and burns through the carpet. :)

Comment: _"You can always just replace it when it catches fire, melts, and burns through the carpet. "_ LOL. The model number matches, so that's a good start. If you look at the 3rd photo it's a little heavier than it looks from the angle shown in the main photo. It's a valid concern though as it's usually left on indefinitely all day long.

Comment: @KenBoone Yeah. It still looks too small. Even in the 3rd picture. (But sure, it looks bigger than in the other pictures.) I don't see 2 lbs in there. Just not happening with that case, as I see it anyway. The problem is... you won't find anyone selling you a decent transformer. They'd never be able to sell it. The price would be too high and US buyers shop on price, not researched quality. That's why I just build all my own stuff, when possible. (And why my wife gets upset because it means I'm the critical path in getting anything done and I'm only one person.)