# How do I calculate a transformer's VA rating for a kitchen grinder based on its power consumption in Watts?

Tags: voltage, transformer, motor, watts, appliances

I imported a 110V kitchen grinder but a 220V one arrived instead.

According to its included specs it consumes 150W and reaches 14500 RPM.

In the case I start looking for a transformer for it, what should be the transformer's VA rating?

I don't understand much of electricity.

I've [read](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/electric/watt-to-va-calculator.html) it depends on a power factor between 0 and 1 which I'm not sure how to find out.

Is this enough information to calculate a VA rating or do I need more information?

Comment: Household devices don't normally differentiate between Watts and VA. When lightly loaded, motors have a low power factor, when heavily loaded (high wattage), their power factor is closer to one. I would be more concerned about the starting power. Converter vendors are recommending 3x to 4x margin when using them with motors. I would get a 600W converter, there doesn't seem to be a huge difference in price.

Comment: Just look for its weight. If you want 150 W, then you need something that weighs about 15 lbs. (See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/268840/38098).) Or, if going cheap then perhaps 8 lbs is okay. But nothing less than that. At 50 Hz instead of 60 Hz, it needs to weigh more.) Heavy iron like this won't be cheap these days.

Comment: For example, [this](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hammond-Manufacturing/167H200?qs=2EywpuXRhvpMcqNm%252B7tnEg%3D%3D) is close (not exact, but gives an idea.) Note that it weighs in at 6 lbs. (Which means to me that it isn't quite good enough. But it's what they have.) Or [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hammond-manufacturing/298CT/2358255), which is more like it and shows you the total cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an actual transformer (a chunk of iron with windings on it, in an enclosure), then a 150VA rating is sufficient, but 200VA would provide lower impedance and thus lower voltage drop under full load.

If you're using a "converter" - an active device that has some electronic components inside, and is usually smaller/lighter than a transformer, and cheaper often as well - then a x4 rating would ensure good performance under all conditions. So, a 600VA rating.

That's the major difference between transformers and "converters": transformers can gracefully handle short duration overload conditions typical with electrical motors on start-up, whereas converters usually have no such margin because they are designed down to a price in a market saturated with cheap junk that barely works.

I suggest you get an actual transformer, not a "transformer" in quotes (nor a converter).