# Motherboard powered by a charger converting AC to DC while using internal switching power supplies which uses AC as input?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, charger, motherboard

I'm confused: from what I understand, switching power supplies (like [this one](https://youtu.be/2KfvxRZ_37Q?t=542)) output DC from AC input.

But if it's true, why do (most?) motherboards use several internal switching powers supplies ([e.g. to output, 3.3V, 5V, 19V...](https://youtu.be/-FMic_Pr-HY?t=2449)) while being powered by a charger that converts AC to DC?

How could these internal switching power supply work since they are powered with DC from the charger?

(Sorry for the basic question)

Comment: motherboards are not powered by a `charger` ... they are powered by a `power supply`

Comment: @jsotola Do you mean that a charger is only to charge a battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm confused: from what I understand, switching power supplies output
> DC from AC input.*

Depending on the design and, the goals, a switching power supply may: -

- Output DC from AC (off-line SMPS)
- Output DC from DC (DC-to-DC converter)
- Output AC from DC (power inverter)
- Output AC from AC (cyclo-converter)

> *why do (most?) motherboards use several internal switching powers supplies (e.g. to output, 3.3V, 5V, 19V...) while being powered by a
> charger that converts AC to DC?*

There's more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andy's answer I found an answer to my question behind: **why is AC rectified to DC, then converted again into AC?**

> the point is to control the frequency. Once you have DC power, you can
> pretty much drive the inverter at any frequency you want.
>
> It is difficult to convert one frequency to another, but it is
> relatively easy to convert DC into any frequency you want (and to
> rectify AC power to DC).

Details:

> Think of the inverter as a switch that reverses polarity. If on one
> side you have DC, then you can switch back and forth as you want. The
> faster you go, the higher the frequency on the output side. You can
> pick any frequency you want, there are no "hard" or "easy"
> frequencies. They try to do the same thing with AC power on the input.
> Unless the frequencies match up, the output will be an ugly mess. AC
> power is very easy to convert from one voltage to another, using a
> transformer. But the frequency on the input and output side of the
> transformer are the same.

Thanks to M Quack from the [physicsforums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/whats-the-point-of-converting-ac-to-dc-and-then-back-to-ac.580911/)